# Magento2 Override getOrderOptions() in plugin

Tags: magento2, overrides

Magento2 override this function getOrderOptions() which is in the file

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Type/AbstractType.php
```

This is a abstract class. Please guide

```
public function aroundGetOrderOptions(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType $subject,callable $proceed) {
        // do stuff 

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/customisable_option_data.log');
                                     $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
                                     $logger->addWriter($writer);
                                     $logger->info('reached');

        $result = $proceed();
        // $result .= '';
        return $result;
}


<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType">
     <plugin name="extra-data" type="XYZ\Checkout\Model\AbstractTypePlugin"/>
</type>
```

Comment: Original function has a param, you have missed that.I have posted the answer. You can see where you did the mistake

Answer (score 0):

The abstract classes never get instantiated you won't have an `\Interceptor` class generated that should call the plugins.

So you can not created `plugin` for this one.

Comment: Yes I created, but not working please guide

Comment: Due to Abstract Class, you can not able to create plugin for this class.

Comment: What should I do in this case?

Comment: first possible then try observer or something which fulfill your requirement, and lastly you can try preference. If answer help, please upvote and accepted as solution so it will help other in community.

Comment: Can I use preference for this?

Comment: you can try, but remember this is abstract class so it will affected all places where this implmeneted.

Comment: Can you please provide feedback I am adding code in my question –

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plugin on `getOrderOptions` . Class rewrite is not possible.

**Plugin class will be :**

```
namespace {YourClassNameSpace}
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType;

class AbstractTypePlugin
{
    /**
     * @param AbstractType $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param Product $product
     * @return array
     */
    public function aroundGetOrderOptions(AbstractType $subject, callable $proceed, $product): array
    {
        // TODO: Implement plugin method.
        return $proceed($product);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide feedback I am adding code in my question

Comment: Original function is has a param that should also be in around plugin

Comment: What about this variable return $optionArr;?

Comment: donot understant?

Comment: Following file

vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Type/AbstractType.php

getOrderOptions() is also returning $optionArr

I have made change in that array in aroundGetOrderOptions

How can I return the new update $optionArr?